# Greatest Number of Information Bits (more so a simple question in computation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coding-theory

> Let $C$ be the radix $3$ $2$-error correcting linear code with $m=4$ check bits.
>   What is the greatest possible number of information bits $k$ in $C$?

I have been instructed to use the Sphere-Packing Bound:
$$|C|\sum_{i=0}^t{n\choose i}(r-1)^i\leq r^n. $$
As $|C$| is linear, this implies $|C|=r^k$ ($r$ denotes the radix). It is known that $m=n-k$. Thus,
\begin{align}
3^k\sum_{i=0}^2{k+4\choose i}2^i\leq 3^{k+4} \\
3^k\left({k+4\choose 0}+2{k+4\choose 1}+4{k+4\choose 2}\right)\leq 3^{k+4} \\
1+2(k+4)+4{k+4\choose 2}\leq 3^{4}. \\
(k+4)+2{k+4\choose 2}\leq 40
\end{align}
My question is, how do you simplify this last line to find an upper bound of $k$? I am very rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$(k+4)+2((k+4)(k+3)/2)=(k+4)^2\leq 40,$$ by definition of the binomial ceefficient, which gives $k=2,$  as the largest integer satisfying the inequality.